# Knuth-Morris-Pratt Fail table

Tags: algorithm, knuth-morris-pratt

I am studying for an exam I have and I am looking over the Knuth-Morris-Pratt algorithm. What is going to be on the exam is the Fail table and DFA construction. I understand DFA construction, but I don't really understand how to make the fail table.

If I have an example of a pattern "abababc" how do I build a fail table from this? The solution is:

Fail table:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7

0 0 0 1 2 3 4 0

but how do I get that? No code just an explanation of how to get that is necessary.

Comment: If you're just looking for an explanation of the algorithm [cs.se] would be a better place to ask.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738130/understanding-the-knuth-morris-prattkmp-failure-function

Answer (score 5):

The value of cell `i` in the fail table for string `s` is defined as follows: take the substring of `s` that ends at position `i`, and the value in the cell is the length of the longest proper(not the whole string) sufix of this substring that is equal to its prefix of the same length.

Let's take your example and consider the value for `6`. The substring of `s` with length 6 is `ababab`. It has 6 suffixes: `babab`, `abab`, `bab`, `ab` and `b` on the other hand its proper prefixes are  `ababa`, `abab`, `aba`, `ab` and `a`. Now it is easy to see that the sufixes that are equal to prefixes of the same length are `abab` and `ab`. Of these the longer is `abab` and thus the value in cell 6 is the its length - `4`.

Comment: Is this the only way to calculate the mismatch table for the DFA? I think the implementation of this will be having  a complexity of O(n^3).

Comment: It is somewhat easy to note that the complexity is not more than square and if you give it a bit more thought you will note that in fact if properly implemented the algorithm will have complexity in the order of O(n).

Comment: Thanks @Ivaylo Strandjev for the clarification. Indeed the complexity comes out to be linear. In fact I just implemented the mismatch table as outlined in the [presentation](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/21PatternMatching.pdf) at slide 20.

Answer (score 0):

Pattern P = {abababc}
P[0] = 'a'. P[1] = 'b'. P[2] = 'a'. P[3] = 'b'. P[4] = 'a'. P[5] = 'b'. P[6] = 'c'.

The motive of the Fail Table is to identify the maximum possible shift (such that we would not miss out on any pattern matching, but would also not make unnecessary comparison), if first "i" character of the pattern string are matching and the break is found at the i+1 th character.

The number in the Fail Table indicates how many character still continues to match after the shift if the first i character of the pattern matches to the text.

Let FailTable be FT[].

FT[1] - 'a' matches with text. Break found at 'b'(P[1]). Do we have a proper suffix of 'a' which matches the proper prefix of 'a'? Ans is NO. So length of the String which still continues to match after the shift is 0. Hence FT[1] = 0.

FT[2] - 'ab' matches with text. Break found at 'a' (P[2]). Do we have a proper suffix of 'ab' which matches the proper prefix of 'ab'? Ans is NO. So length of the String which still continues to match after the shift is 0. Hence FT[2] = 0.

FT[3] - 'aba' matches with text. Break found at 'b' (P[3]). Do we have a proper suffix of 'aba' which matches the proper prefix of 'aba'? Ans is YES ('a'). So length of the String which still continues to match after the shift is 1. Hence FT[3] = 1.

FT[4] - 'abab' matches with text. Break found at 'a' (P[4]). Do we have a proper suffix of 'abab' which matches the proper prefix of 'abab'? Ans is YES('ab'). So length of the String which still continues to match after the shift is 2. Hence FT[4] = 2.

FT[5] - 'ababa' matches with text. Break found at 'b' (P[5]). Do we have a proper suffix of 'ababa' which matches the proper prefix of 'ababa'? Ans is YES('aba'). So length of the String which still continues to match after the shift is 3. Hence FT[5] = 3.

FT[6] - 'ababab' matches with text. Break found at 'a' (P[6]). Do we have a proper suffix of 'ababab' which matches the proper prefix of 'ababab'? Ans is YES('abab'). So length of the String which still continues to match after the shift is 4. Hence FT[6] = 4.

FT[7] - 'abababc' matches with text. No break found at all, Pattern matched with the text. Do we have a proper suffix of 'abababc' which matches the proper prefix of 'abababc'? Ans is NO. So length of the String which still continues to match after the shift is 0. Hence FT[7] = 0.

Hence the final array is FT = [0,0,1,2,3,4,0]

Hope it helps!